# How can i resolve unitOfWork every request with Ninject

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ninject, unit-of-work, n-tier-architecture

I use MVC,EF5 and three layer. (DAL,BLL,UI) I 've apply unit of work pattern to my project. And i want to resolve unit of work class every controller's request. And after execute i run commit method. I 've set ninject as following code. But it's create about 10 times. So My bll class raise different context error.

```
 //i want to change this every controller request. I don't want to use InSingletonScope() because it be cause to dead lock etc..
_kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>().InRequestScope();

//sample manager 
public class BannerManager:IBannerService
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public BannerManager(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }
}
```

Comment: When in `InRequestScope` doesn't find a `HttpContext.Current` it behaves like `InTransientScope`. Maybe that's your issue here? Another possible cause is if you setup ninject in a way that it creates new kernels all the time. You might want to check that, too.

Comment: InRequestScope() will create a new instance for every request, however, there are many factors that can affect this.. so you need to show us your complete configuration code, not just that one line.

Comment: i've been set ninject wrong. i remove ninject. i download mvc package and i setup it again . so all modules works fine. thanks guy.